# Помогите выбрать структуру данных для проекта

Tags: java

Разрабатываю приложение для хранения информаци обо всех студентах университета. Все должно быть распределено по факультетам, направлениям, и еще надо предусмотреть также преподавателей.

Какую лучше структуру данных выбрать?

Пишу на java. Сначала все реализовывал с помощью ArrayList, в которых содержатся другие списки. Пришла в голову идея о хеш-таблице, но тогда проблема будет с поиском и выборкой, ибо нужно все данные выводить в таблицу, и там далее сортировать по необходимости. Думал множества использовать, а точнее SortedSet, но не уверен.

Также студенты могут добавляться, удалятся, переходить на другие специальности. Нужна полная редактируемость данных.

Comment: Для подобных целей существуют базы данных

Comment: Я знаю , но мне нужно использовать именно коллекции , по этому и обратился за помощью.

Comment: В вашем случае, надо использовать БД, в коллекциях ничего хранить нельзя. Или вы собираетесь при каждом перезапуске заставлять пользователя вбивать всех студентов и преподавателей?

Comment: Нет , я думал в файле хранить , и с файла читать

Comment: Вы не можете заранее определить, какие структуры данных вам понадобятся. (Ну или сможете, если у вас в голове будет дизайн всего проекта.) Пользуйтесь какими угодно структурами данных (хоть тем же `ArrayList`'ом), когда увидите, какие операции вам реально нужны, поменяете структуры данных на более подходящие.

Comment: Если данных немного, можете хранить в XML. Для сериализации/десериализации - JAXB, для поиска - XPath. Сторонние библиотеки не понадобятся.

Comment: SQlite Вам помощь - нет сложностей с подключением,  не нужно запускать сервер, в интернете полно туториалов.

Answer (score 1):

Храните данные в xml, как предложил @enzo.

1. Набросайте пример такой xml.
2. По примеру создайте xsd схему.
3. По xsd схеме сгенерируйте с помощью [xjc](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) java объекты для сохранения и загрузки данных в xml с исользованием JAXB.

Сгенерированный java объекты и будут необходимой Вам структурой даных (там все будет с использованием `List`, кончено).

Далее, в зависимости от того как Вам надо представить данные, будете конвертирвать исходную структуру в структуру представления. Для структуры представления рекомендую использовать структуры [данных из guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained), например, `Table`.